# What's wrong with deleting a file?

Tags: c++

I wanna delete txt file when the password has a lowercase letter.

Creating file code:

```
FILE *files[20];
            char filename[20];
            sprintf(filename, "%d.txt", i);
            files[i] = fopen(filename, "w");

            
            string login, pass;
            //wprowadzanie zmian w licznie kont
            fstream liczb;
            liczb.open("liczbakont.txt", ios::out);
            liczb<<i;
            //tworzenie plików dla poszczególnych kont
            fstream plik(to_string(i)+".txt");
            plik<<"\n";
            cout<<"Podaj login: "<<endl;
```

Removal:

```
cout<<"pass: "<<endl;
            cin>>pass;
            if(islower (haslo[0]) )
            {
                if( remove(to_string(i)+".txt") == 0)
            }
```

What is wrong?

[Error] cannot convert 'std::basic_string' to 'const char*' for argument '1' to 'int remove(const char*)'
[Error] expected primary-expression before '}' token
[Error] expected declaration before '}' token

Comment: `remove` wants a c-string (`const char *`) not a `std::string`. But `to_string()` returns a `std::string`. You can use the `std::string::c_str()` function to get a c-string from a `std::string`.

Comment: If you look at the error message it says that the argument to `remove` must be a `const char *`. This is because `remove` is really a C function, which doesn't know anything about C++ objects like `std::string`.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp so what do i have to change or add?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the declaration of the function that you call:

```
int remove( const char* fname );
```

Pay particular attention to the type of the parameter. It is `const char*`. The type of the expression `to_string(i)+".txt"` which you used as the argument however isn't `const char*`. The type is `std::string`.

You cannot pass an argument of one type into a function that is expecting an argument of another type - except when the former type is implicitly convertible to the latter. `std::string` is not implicitly convertible to `const char*`. This is what the error message told you:

> [Error] cannot convert 'std::basic_string' to 'const char*' for argument '1' to 'int remove(const char*)'

`std::string` does however have a member function `c_str` which returns a `const char*`. Now check back at the declaration of `std::remove` and you'll find that this matches with the type of the parameter. As such a trivial fix is:

```
std::remove((to_string(i)+".txt").c_str())
```

Even better, I recommend using `std::filesystem` instead:

```
std::filesystem::remove(to_string(i)+".txt")
```

> [Error] expected primary-expression before '}' token [Error] expected declaration before '}' token

This error tells you that your if-statement is ill-formed. Example:

```
// wrong
{
    if(condition)
}

// correct
{
    if(condition)
        statement;
}
```

Comment: [Error] 'std::fstream' has no member named 'remove'

Comment: @KarolPawlak Read the answer again.

Answer (score 0):

- It seems the type of expected and actual argument don't match. You can use [`c_str()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str) to get `const char*` from `std::string`.
- There are no statement after the `if` statement, so it invokes the second error. Add some statement to execute or remove the extra `if` statement.

Add some statement (an empty statement `;` in this case):

```
            if(islower (haslo[0]) )
            {
                if( remove((to_string(i)+".txt").c_str()) == 0);
            }
```

Remove the extra `if`:

```
            if(islower (haslo[0]) )
            {
                remove((to_string(i)+".txt").c_str()) == 0;
            }
```